# how to properly integrate Admob in a flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, admob

I've been trying to add `Admob` to my `flutter` application, but it keeps crashing..

Here is what I've tried to do :

I've added [This](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob#-readme-tab-) package to my `pubspec.yaml`

Then I've added this `meta-data` to my `AndroidManifest.xml` file :

```xml
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
  android:value="ca-app-pub-here-is-my_app_id_in_admob"/>
```

**result**

I get this error when I try to run the program (please note that I didn't add any ads to my `.dart` files yet`

```
   > File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@d8f9ce4' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@5977de6b' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: you can refer to this step-by-step tutorial:
[link](https://yassinebenkhay.com/how-to-integrate-admob-ads-in-flutter/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `flutter clean` and it will be solved

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it is not clear whether you use Firebase. You are using the "firebase_admob" package, which requires Google Service file from Firebase inside your project. If you no need a Firebase, I recommend you package [admob_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter). This package simple and works fine in my projects (but it no support Firebase integration).